# How to add headers in Parse Calls in Parse iOS SDK?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-ios-sdk

I am trying to add some headers to all my parse calls on a global level in my iOS project (using swift).
However i am unable to find a way to do so.
Can someone help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **ParseClientConfiguration** class works fine!
Example:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "APLICATION_ID"
        $0.server = "SERVER_URL"
}
configuration.urlSessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["HEADER_KEY" : "HEADER_VALUE"]
```